# Unable to copy files from local system to local server

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, filesystem, disk-usage

When I am trying copy data onto a local server in our college LAN from my local system, I'm getting this error

> No space left on device

However, I am able to copy onto my colleague's system who gave a server access to it. I know for sure there is lots of space on the local server machine and still it gives me this error message. I do not understand this behaviour.

I'm copying data using file explorer. I saw previously questions asked on the same title but most of the solutions didn't work for me. for example certain commands such as `df -i`, `df -h`, etc. throw results that are not matching with most of the answers or questions that are put up.

Results of `df -i`:

```
Filesystem      Inodes     IUsed    IFree     IUse%  Mounted on
udev            2037311    507      2036804    1%    /dev
tmpfs           2042377    714      2041663    1%    /run
/dev/sda1       60006400   835398   59171002   2%    /
tmpfs           2042377    236      2042141    1%    /dev/shm
tmpfs           2042377      6      2042371    1%    /run/lock
tmpfs           2042377     16      2042361    1%    /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2042377     38      2042339    1%    /run/user/1000
```

Results of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       902G   96G  760G  12% /
tmpfs           7.8G   81M  7.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G   92K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

A snapshot

[image: File Explorer]

As you can see the remote server named a Public is shown to be mounted on my system. A closer snapshot will show you that I can choose a file from the remote server(Public) and hit `ctrlc+c` for copying and hit `ctrl+v` on my local system to paste the chosen in my system. The reverse is not possible because I'm getting an error that says insufficient space.

[image: nautilus2]

The output of `df -h` after public is shown to be mounted on my system.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       902G   95G  761G  12% /
tmpfs           7.8G  291M  7.6G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G   92K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The output of `df -i` after public is shown to be mounted on my system.

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            2037311    509  2036802    1% /dev
tmpfs           2042377    726  2041651    1% /run
/dev/sda1      60006400 866544 59139856    2% /
tmpfs           2042377    258  2042119    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2042377      6  2042371    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2042377     16  2042361    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2042377     38  2042339    1% /run/user/1000
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "copying data using file explorer"? Are you using a mapped network drive in windows?

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand:  "copy onto a local server" to me means a different machine (via `scp` or something) meaning the `df` output is unhelpful as it shows you local machine & not unmounted servers (your output doesn't show any servers) you're copying to. 'file explorer' sounds like a windoze app (did you mean nautilus?) so I need more information  (copy from? (or at least size of data) to?? using what? (what protocol are you using to access the servers? as I don't see any mounted))

Comment: @muclux  By "copying data using file explorer" I mean copying files to a file server that has about 100TB capacity offered by the college to back up our project files using nautilus of Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Comment: @guiverc By "copy onto a local server" I mean a server, a different machine. By file explorer of Ubuntu, its the nautilus I mean. With regards to the size, I'm unable to copy any size of data. Literally nothing I'm able to copy/move onto the the server. My colleagues part of the same network are able to. But I'm not able to.

Comment: So what do you do in nautilus to copy your files to the college server? You should have a mounted file system (nfs, cifs) from the college server in order to do so, but your df output shows none (as @guiverc already pointed out).

Comment: @muclux I updated the question to include a snapshot that'll give more clarity.

Comment: You still do not tell what you do to establish a connection to the remote server. You don't have any nfs-mounted filesystems. What do you try to do with your files in nautilus to send them to the server?

Comment: I can't see an update with a snapshot in your original post.

Comment: ok, now I see your snapshot.  Could you now please repeat the `df -h` command while `public` is mounted?

Comment: I've done it and updated my original post.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how you can use a network folder named 'public' which is not visible in the `df` output. How do you connect to this server 192.168.20.72?

Comment: I connect to the server 192.168.20.72 using the smb://192.168.20.72. I am able to copy stuff from the server but not able to upload/copy/move files onto the server. Of late I am able to copy only pdf's of small sizes(KB's).

Comment: There is probably a limited size of your samba share on the public server and you have (nearly) reached this limit. Does your colleague use the same share?

Comment: Ye. my colleagues can upload/copy/move files onto the server while I cannot using samba.